# package uninstalls when adding a new dependency?

Tags: bash, shell, docker, alpine-linux

In the entrypoint script of a docker -based on alpine linux-, I have the following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "============== START ============"
echo $@
NOLOAD=0
FILE=""

RET=1

if [ !  -f /initialized ]; then
  echo "not initialized"
  apk add --virtual .init-deps bash
  echo "bash installed"
  echo "Building from server"
  apk add --virtual .init-deps git
  echo "git installed"
  bash load_git.sh "${GIT_SERVER}" "${GIT_USERNAME}" "${GIT_PASSWORD}" "${GIT_BRANCH}"
  RET=$?
  echo cloning done
fi
echo "just before purging all dependencies"
apk --purge del .init-deps
```

I expect `bash` to install, as well as git and the run the `load_git.sh` script using bash. I am literary logging every other line, but am getting some strange results -before the `load_git.sh` script is even run:

```
============== START ============

not initialized
(1/6) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(2/6) Installing ncurses-terminfo (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(3/6) Installing ncurses-libs (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(4/6) Installing readline (8.0.1-r0)
(5/6) Installing bash (5.0.11-r1)
Executing bash-5.0.11-r1.post-install
(6/6) Installing .init-deps (20200109.202215)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r8.trigger
OK: 18 MiB in 24 packages
bash installed
Building from server
(1/12) Installing ca-certificates (20191127-r0)
(2/12) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.40.0-r0)
(3/12) Installing libcurl (7.67.0-r0)
(4/12) Installing expat (2.2.9-r1)
(5/12) Installing pcre2 (10.34-r1)
(6/12) Installing git (2.24.1-r0)
(7/12) Upgrading .init-deps (20200109.202215 -> 20200109.202216)
(8/12) Purging bash (5.0.11-r1)
Executing bash-5.0.11-r1.pre-deinstall
(9/12) Purging readline (8.0.1-r0)
(10/12) Purging ncurses-libs (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(11/12) Purging ncurses-terminfo (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(12/12) Purging ncurses-terminfo-base (6.1_p20191130-r0)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r8.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20191127-r0.trigger
OK: 25 MiB in 25 packages
git installed
/init.sh: line 17: bash: not found
cloning done
outside if statement to get source
just before purging all dependencies
Build failed, starting shell
```

I can't wrap my head around the fact that upon installing git it also purging bash, this makes no sense at all.

EDIT: *this only happens when starting the docker over an ssh connection in a synology nas*, when using a local docker image and starting it locally it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Whats in load_git.sh?

Comment: Another script (which should download the latest version that has been reviewed from the git). - There is an echo at top of the script and I know it isn't run. Putting just `echo "outdir"` show that either (nor is the return variable set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks what's happening here is that the `apk add --virtual .init-deps` option creates a virtual package and makes it depend on the other packages that just got installed.  When you do it a second time, it creates a new virtual package that depends (only) on the second set of packages, and upgrades the virtual package to the new version; when you do that, the first set of packages gets automatically uninstalled.

There are two easy workarounds here: either remove this `--virtual .init-deps` option, from both lines, or combine all of your installation into a single `apk add` line.

(It's usually not great practice to download packages on container startup, particularly since deleting and recreating containers is a fairly routine operation.  Better practice would be to do this once in the image's Dockerfile

```
RUN apk add bash git
```

but also to consider whether you actually need either of these tools to run the application packaged in your image.)

Comment: Well the container will -on first load- download the code from git, and it uses bash to actually handle the potential errors from git and show a good log. Since after the initial load bash and git are no longer needed, or if I use another source control scheme like hg/svn another package needs to be installed, I think it's better to dynamically install those packages, and to clean up after your mess and remove those when used.

Comment: The path I’d recommend is cloning the repository on your host before you run Docker anything, and in your Dockerfile `COPY` the application source into the image.  Then the image is a fixed independent copy of the application, it doesn’t depend on having a source control tool (or its credentials) at startup time, and the container won’t fail if the external source-control system is unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing this and managed with the script below on a remote machine:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ !  -f /initialized ]; then
  apk add --virtual .init-deps bash
  apk add --virtual .init-deps git
  bash -c "bash works"
fi
```

But consecutive runs have varying results:

```
ubuntu@dev:~$ docker run c81a2d3a5f6b
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/6) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(2/6) Installing ncurses-terminfo (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(3/6) Installing ncurses-libs (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(4/6) Installing readline (8.0.1-r0)
(5/6) Installing bash (5.0.11-r1)
Executing bash-5.0.11-r1.post-install
(6/6) Installing .init-deps (20200109.224208)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r8.trigger
OK: 15 MiB in 20 packages
(1/12) Installing ca-certificates (20191127-r0)
(2/12) Installing nghttp2-libs (1.40.0-r0)
(3/12) Installing libcurl (7.67.0-r0)
(4/12) Installing expat (2.2.9-r1)
(5/12) Installing pcre2 (10.34-r1)
(6/12) Installing git (2.24.1-r0)
(7/12) Upgrading .init-deps (20200109.224208 -> 20200109.224209)
(8/12) Purging bash (5.0.11-r1)
Executing bash-5.0.11-r1.pre-deinstall
(9/12) Purging readline (8.0.1-r0)
(10/12) Purging ncurses-libs (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(11/12) Purging ncurses-terminfo (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(12/12) Purging ncurses-terminfo-base (6.1_p20191130-r0)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r8.trigger
Executing ca-certificates-20191127-r0.trigger
OK: 22 MiB in 21 packages
/test.sh: line 5: bash: not found
```

---

```
ubuntu@dev:~$ docker run c81a2d3a5f6b
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.11/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/6) Installing ncurses-terminfo-base (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(2/6) Installing ncurses-terminfo (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(3/6) Installing ncurses-libs (6.1_p20191130-r0)
(4/6) Installing readline (8.0.1-r0)
(5/6) Installing bash (5.0.11-r1)
Executing bash-5.0.11-r1.post-install
(6/6) Installing .init-deps (20200109.224207)
Executing busybox-1.31.1-r8.trigger
OK: 15 MiB in 20 packages
OK: 15 MiB in 20 packages
bash works
```

So I think this is a timing problem in apk